# \tkzGetAngle strange behavior

Tags: tkz-euclide

I want to draw several different triangles ABC with the angles marked and the angle value written in it. Thanks to answers on on another question, I've managed to get this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} %% om allerhande objecten te gebruiken zoals gradenboog...
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}


\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ddToddmmss[1]{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\deg@tmp{#1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\min@tmp{(#1-\deg@tmp)*60}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\Min@tmp{\min@tmp}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\sec@tmp{(\min@tmp-floor(\min@tmp))*60}%
\ensuremath{\deg@tmp^\circ \Min@tmp ' \sec@tmp ''}}
\makeatother


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=9,xmin=0,xmax=15]
\tkzClip
\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{1/3/A, 7/8/B, 12/1/C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C) \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C) \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C)

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.4](C,A,B);
\tkzFindAngle(C,A,B) \tkzGetAngle{angleCAB};
%\FPround\angleBAC\angleCAB{2}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 2.3](C,A,B){\ddToddmmss{\angleCAB}};  

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.4](A,B,C);
\tkzFindAngle(A,B,C) \tkzGetAngle{angleABC};
%\FPround\angleABC\angleABC{2}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 2.3](A,B,C){\ddToddmmss{\angleABC}};

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.4](B,C,A);
\tkzFindAngle(B,C,A) \tkzGetAngle{angleBCA};
%\FPround\angleBCA\angleBCA{2}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 2.3](B,C,A){\ddToddmmss{\angleBCA}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=9,xmin=0,xmax=15]
\tkzClip
\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{1/3/A, 7/8/B, 12/5/C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C) \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C) \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C)

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.4](C,A,B);
\tkzFindAngle(C,A,B) \tkzGetAngle{angleCAB};
%\FPround\angleBAC\angleCAB{2}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 2.3](C,A,B){\ddToddmmss{\angleCAB}};  

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.4](A,B,C);
\tkzFindAngle(A,B,C) \tkzGetAngle{angleABC};
%\FPround\angleABC\angleABC{2}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 2.3](A,B,C){\ddToddmmss{\angleABC}};

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.4](B,C,A);
\tkzFindAngle(B,C,A) \tkzGetAngle{angleBCA};
%\FPround\angleBCA\angleBCA{2}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 2.3](B,C,A){\ddToddmmss{\angleBCA}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: triangles 1 and 2]

Problem is, in version 2, where point C is higher than point A, he takes the wrong angle.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at how `\tkzFindAngle` is defined in `tkz-obj-angles.tex`, you will see that it uses quite simple way to calculate the angle.

```
\def\tkzFindAngle(#1,#2,#3){%
\begingroup
      \tkzFindSlopeAngle(#2,#1)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@FirstAngle}
      \tkzFindSlopeAngle(#2,#3)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@SecondAngle}
      \FPadd\tkz@Angle{\tkz@SecondAngle}{-\tkz@FirstAngle}
     \global\let\tkzAngleResult\tkz@Angle
\endgroup
}
```

Similarly `\tkz@LabelAngle` calculates quite simply where to put the label.

```
\def\tkz@LabelAngle[#1](#2,#3,#4)#5{%
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{tkzlabelangle/.cd,
         dist  = 1}
\pgfqkeys{/tkzlabelangle}{#1}
\tkzFindSlopeAngle(#3,#2)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@dirOne}
\tkzFindSlopeAngle(#3,#4)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@dirTwo}
\FPeval\labelAngle{( \tkz@dirOne +\tkz@dirTwo)/2}
\path (#3) --+(\labelAngle:\labeldist) node[/tkzmkangle/.cd,#1] {#5};
\endgroup
}
```

Whereas `\tkzMarkAngle` uses a lot more complex calculation for the angle in `\tkzDrawArcRAN` to mark the angle.

```
\def\tkzDrawArcRAN[#1](#2,#3)(#4,#5){%
 \begingroup
 \pgfmathparse{#4}\edef\tkz@FirstAngle{\pgfmathresult}%
 \pgfmathparse{#5}\edef\tkz@SecondAngle{\pgfmathresult}%
  \pgfmathgreaterthan{\tkz@FirstAngle}{0}
  \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=1 pt\relax%
    \pgfmathgreaterthan{\tkz@FirstAngle}{\tkz@SecondAngle}
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=1 pt\relax%
     \pgfmathsubtract{\tkz@FirstAngle}{360}
     \edef\tkz@FirstAngle{\pgfmathresult}%
 \fi
 \else
     \pgfmathgreaterthan{\tkz@FirstAngle}{\tkz@SecondAngle}
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=1 pt\relax%
     \pgfmathadd{\tkz@SecondAngle}{360}
     \edef\tkz@SecondAngle{\pgfmathresult}%
 \fi
 \fi
     \draw[shift = {(#2)},/drawarc/.cd,#1]%
       (\tkz@FirstAngle:#3) arc (\tkz@FirstAngle:\tkz@SecondAngle:#3);
\endgroup
}
```

Using the same angle normalization as `\tkzMarkAngle` is probably what you are after.

```
\makeatletter
\def\tkzFindAngle(#1,#2,#3){%
\begingroup
  \tkzFindSlopeAngle(#2,#1)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@FirstAngle}
  \tkzFindSlopeAngle(#2,#3)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@SecondAngle}
  \my@NormalizeAngle(\tkz@FirstAngle,\tkz@SecondAngle)
  \FPadd\tkz@Angle{\my@SecondAngle}{-\my@FirstAngle}
  \global\let\tkzAngleResult\tkz@Angle
\endgroup
}

\def\tkz@LabelAngle[#1](#2,#3,#4)#5{%
\begingroup
  \pgfkeys{tkzlabelangle/.cd,dist=1}
  \pgfqkeys{/tkzlabelangle}{#1}
  \tkzFindSlopeAngle(#3,#2)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@dirOne}
  \tkzFindSlopeAngle(#3,#4)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@dirTwo}
  \my@NormalizeAngle(\tkz@dirOne,\tkz@dirTwo)
  \FPeval\labelAngle{(\my@FirstAngle +\my@SecondAngle)/2}
  \path (#3) --+(\labelAngle:\labeldist) node[/tkzmkangle/.cd,#1] {#5};
\endgroup
}

\def\my@NormalizeAngle(#1,#2){%
\begingroup
  \pgfmathparse{#1}\xdef\my@FirstAngle{\pgfmathresult}%
  \pgfmathparse{#2}\xdef\my@SecondAngle{\pgfmathresult}%
  \pgfmathgreaterthan{\my@FirstAngle}{0}
  \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=1 pt\relax%
    \pgfmathgreaterthan{\my@FirstAngle}{\my@SecondAngle}
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=1 pt\relax%
      \pgfmathsubtract{\my@FirstAngle}{360}
      \xdef\my@FirstAngle{\pgfmathresult}%
    \fi
  \else
    \pgfmathgreaterthan{\my@FirstAngle}{\my@SecondAngle}
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=1 pt\relax%
      \pgfmathadd{\my@SecondAngle}{360}
      \xdef\my@SecondAngle{\pgfmathresult}%
    \fi
  \fi
\endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your remark ! I need to make an update version of tkz-euclide