# Positioning \tkzLabelAngle Inside Angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I'm interested in getting the text of \tkzLabelAngle to always position inside the angle. I'm randomly generating these triangles, so I'm hoping there is a general solution that will work for all angles rather than manually positioning each one. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason as to why some labels are outside the triangles as you can see in the image.

I've tried various strategies including defining a pos or size (the latter of which ends up giving me errors), changing the size of the text, drawing the triangles with \tkz* commands, changing the order of the angles (although I verified it was labeling the inside angle with \tkzMarkAngle) e.g. from (B,A,C) to (C,A,B).

So, other than manually defining pos for each of the outliers, is there a better strategy to get the angles in the right position all the time (given that all angles are generated randomly)?

Thanks for any assistance.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=19mm,vmargin=13mm,includeheadfoot,headheight=27.6pt,headsep=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings,calc,positioning}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{12pt}{8pt}
\bigskip
\begin{minipage}[b][7cm][t]{0.05\textwidth} \footnotesize 1. \end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][7cm][t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(15:3.3){B}
\tkzDefPoint(127:2.542){C}
\draw[thick](A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\tkzLabelAngle[](C,B,A){\small $29^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[](B,A,C){\small $112^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[](A,C,B){\small $39^{\circ}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][7cm][t]{0.05\textwidth} \footnotesize 2. \end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][7cm][t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.6]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(177:3.2){B}
\tkzDefPoint(205:2.614){C}
\draw[thick](A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\tkzLabelAngle[](C,B,A){\small $54^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[](B,A,C){\small $28^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[](A,C,B){\small $98^{\circ}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][7cm][t]{0.05\textwidth} \footnotesize 3. \end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][7cm][t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(9:4.1){B}
\tkzDefPoint(74:4.636){C}
\draw[thick](A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\tkzLabelAngle[](C,B,A){\small $63^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[](B,A,C){\small $65^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[](A,C,B){\small $52^{\circ}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][7cm][t]{0.05\textwidth} \footnotesize 4. \end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][7cm][t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(109:3.7){B}
\tkzDefPoint(209:4.76){C}
\draw[thick](A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\tkzLabelAngle[](C,B,A){\small $46^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[](B,A,C){\small $100^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[](A,C,B){\small $34^{\circ}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][7cm][t]{0.05\textwidth} \footnotesize 5. \end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][7cm][t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(290:4){B}
\tkzDefPoint(416:3.035){C}
\draw[thick](A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\tkzLabelAngle[](C,B,A){\small $23^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[](B,A,C){\small $126^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[](A,C,B){\small $31^{\circ}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][7cm][t]{0.05\textwidth} \footnotesize 6. \end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][7cm][t]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(67:4.6){B}
\tkzDefPoint(89:3.803){C}
\draw[thick](A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\tkzLabelAngle[](C,B,A){\small $53^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[](B,A,C){\small $22^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[](A,C,B){\small $105^{\circ}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: I had the same problem... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151667/tkzgetangle-strange-behavior

Comment: There are some bugs in my packages. I have a solution and I will update the package on ctan in few days